# Side Menu Push Content When Expanding

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar menu that expands on hover. Works really really great, but I'd like to make it to where when it expands IF it touches another element it will push it over. I say this because my content will be centered so it comes down to the users resolution for this to happen. On my page I have one other element besides my menu and it is an error(i triggered this error on purpose for testing). The error element should be 100% width. Again this is here for testing purposes. Right now the sidebar is overlapping the error element even when not expanded. What can I do to solve all of this?

HTML:

```
<div class="isa_error">
  <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
Sorry, an error happened. Please try again later<br>
Error 2 : mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/profile/settings/mysqli_connect.php on line 2 
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/errors.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mainStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/sidebar.css">
</head><html>
 <body>
      <div class="slide-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><span class="navLeft">&equiv;</span><span class="menuTitle">Navigation</span></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="navLeft"></span><span class="navText">Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="navLeft"></span><span class="navText">Gallery</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="navLeft"></span><span class="navText">Request Pilot Cars</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="navLeft"></span><span class="navText">Submit Invoice</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="navLeft"></span><span class="navText">Contact Us</span></a></li>
                <li><span class="navLeft"></span><span class="menuTitle">Site Stats</span></li>
                <li><span class="navLeft"></span><span class="menuText">Visitors: <span class="navNumber">001</span></span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="login">
                <li><span class="navLeft"></span><span class="menuTitle">Admin Panel</span></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="navLeft"></span><span class="navText">Login</span></a></li>   

            </ul>
    </div> </body>
</html>
```

Sidebar CSS

```
.navLeft {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.menuTitle { 
  color: #ff6400; 
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 190px;
  font-family: 'Iceland', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
.slide-menu:hover {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: visible;
  background-image: none;
}
.slide-menu {
  background: #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #ff6400;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width .05s linear;
  transition: width .05s linear;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.slide-menu ul {
  margin: 7px 0;
}
.slide-menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
}
.slide-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Iceland;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}
.slide-menu .navText, .slide-menu .menuText {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 190px;
  font-family: 'Iceland', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
.slide-menu .menuText {
  color: #999;
}
.slide-menu .menuText .navNumber {
  background-color: #232323;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
}
.slide-menu ul.login {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.slide-menu li:hover a {
  color: #ff6400;
  text-indent: 30px;
  text-shadow: none!important;
}
```

And the error CSS:

```
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.isa_info, .isa_success, .isa_warning, .isa_error {
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding:12px;
}
.isa_info {
    color: #00529B;
    background-color: #BDE5F8;
}
.isa_success {
    color: #4F8A10;
    background-color: #DFF2BF;
}
.isa_warning {
    color: #9F6000;
    background-color: #FEEFB3;
}
.isa_error {
    color: #D8000C;
    background-color: #FFBABA;
}
.isa_info i, .isa_success i, .isa_warning i, .isa_error i {
    margin:10px 22px;
    font-size:2em;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

My error element is only before my DOCTYPE because that is my PHP error handler and I am making sure it is before everything else(mostly because I am unsure if it will work fully or not if it is not before everything else).

My error elements do use some third party css which is listed, but I will be changing that today once I design my own.

Thanks.

EDIT: You can view my test page at http://profile.jollyrogerpcs.com/

EDIT 2: Including jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f0mqv7yg/

Comment: For future reference jsfiddle.net is a lot more useful! :) :P

Comment: Haha I know, but if I remember correctly doesn't it give you a smaller window than a live demo page? Lol I was just trying to show the full width and everything.

Comment: Giving both also works :r

Comment: True. I'll make a fiddle.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried but for anyone else that wants to give it a go - a simplified jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/e7wjtdo6/)

Comment: hmmm I'm trying to keep it beside it at the moment.

Comment: You should not use tables for layout.

Comment: Sorry forgot the position but same more or less: http://jsfiddle.net/e7wjtdo6/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you just looking to indent the content (error ) part from side menu. add style margin-left : 60 px to isa_error class;
Else want to resize content (error) area while menu expands, then should use javascript or jquery

Comment: It's not just for the error. It's for any future elements on the page. Everything is going to be place into a container element though. For now how can I prevent the overlap? Will I have to use margins?

Comment: '<div class = "isa_error">' going to be called number of times or just once. if number of times then better wrap those in a parent div and give margin-left to the parent div or should be given to each "<div class = "is_error">'